# How to cross domain by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I have API wirte by PHP in address: x
I have UI wirte by html, js, css... in address: y
In address y, in javascript code, I request to address x to get data then Chrome message in control: XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'x'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'y' is therefore not allowed access
How to resolve ?

Comment: Your primary focus here should be on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Does your data happen to be in JSON format?

Comment: I would use a proxy on "address y"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Answer (score 1):

You need to give ;

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: x');
```

On your api in `y` domain for domain `x`. Above code means `Allow "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" for domain x on y server`

Comment: You can explane me more detail ?. I set 
down vote
accept
You need to give ;

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: x'); in code PHP in API server or Js in y server ?

Comment: In order to make ajax request to server y from x, you need to set header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for client domain (x). You cannot make ajax request to different domain, it is blocked according to CORS. In order to make request, you need to allow on y server fo x

Comment: It goes between servers, but OP are using XMLHttpRequest, that means it runs on the client, and **not** "server x".

Comment: i still can not get data :( can you use TeamView and give me resolution

Comment: @TuấnAnh how did you use it? State in your question

Comment: download and install teamview here: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx?pid=google.tv.s.int&gclid=CJDF9u_hsL0CFSVU4godrHUA9Q
then I send to you my ID and my Password. You use it to login to my PC, then you can write code to solve my problem